# What is the idiomatic way of passing a component factory to another component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, idioms

I have a simple list component that renders an array of items.  The item components have more functionality (click handlers, etc.) and there are different types of items I might want to render inside this list component.

I know about higher order components, but they don't seem applicable here, as I'm not wrapping something, but rather generating components from an array.

This is how I've approached it so far, with a functional component for the list:

```
function ResultsList(props)
{
    var items = (props.items || []).map(function(item, i) {
            return <props.ItemComponent
                key={item.id}
                item={item}
                index={i}
                {...props}
            />
        });

    return (
        <ul className="results-list"
            style={{ display: items.length ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
            {items}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

The `ResultsList` component is then used in the `render()` method of another component:

```
render: function()
{
    var items = this.generateItems();

    return (
        <div>Item count: {items.length}</div>
        <ResultsList
            items={items}
            ItemComponent={this.state.itemType == 1 ? ItemType1 : ItemType2}
        />
    )
}
```

Which kind of item to render inside `ResultsList` depends on the component's state, so different item components will be passed in as a prop to the list.

I could also generate the list of items in this `render()` method, and then pass them into `ResultsList` as `props.children`.  Yet somehow encapsulating the list generation inside the `ResultsList` component feels cleaner.  But I may be off here.